# Remove item from SelectList in C#

Tags: c#, selectlist

I have a method in which return me selectList. The certain items of selectList are to be programatically removed on the basis of Key.

```
 public SelectList GetRoutingActionList()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> routingActions = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
                                                        { "Approved", "Approve" },
                                                        { "Return To", "Return To .." }, 
                                                        { "Return To Sender", "Return To Sender" }, 
                                                        { "Disapprove", "Disapprove" },
                                                        { "Set On Hold", "Set On Hold" } 
                                                    };

        SelectList routingActionList = new SelectList(routingActions, "Key", "Value");
        return routingActionList;
    }
```

For eaxmple , I have to remove the item with Key "Disapprove".
Could any one kindly help me to solve this.

Comment: `routingActions.Remove("Disapprove")`?

Comment: The question is not clear. Maybe what you want is removing something from routingActions and  not form the selectList

Comment: The above method returns the selectList to the controller , inside controller I might need to remove certain item. @pinturic

Comment: @impream then see my answer, i explained how you can do that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use `Where()` to filter them and then pass returned object of `List<SelectListItem>` to `SelectList` constructor to get the new SelectList which will not have item with Value **"Disapprove"** this way:

```
public class SomeController
{

   public ActionResult Index()
   {

       SelectList list = GetRoutingActionList();

       list  = new SelectList(list 
                              .Where(x => x.Value != "Disapprove")
                              .ToList(),
                              "Value",
                              "Text");

        return View();
   }

}
```

Comment: Actually GetRoutingActionList() is common method that is called from other controller , and the item from returned selectlist is removed as per requirement in he controller @Ehsan

Comment: you can use the above code in controller or view wherever you need to remove item

Answer (score 3):

```
public SelectList GetRoutingActionList()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> routingActions = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
                                                        { "Approved", "Approve" },
                                                        { "Return To", "Return To .." }, 
                                                        { "Return To Sender", "Return To Sender" }, 
                                                        { "Disapprove", "Disapprove" },
                                                        { "Set On Hold", "Set On Hold" } 
                                                    };

        SelectList routingActionList = new SelectList(routingActions, "Key", "Value");
        return routingActionList.Where(x => x.Key != "Disapprove")
                                   .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove it from dictionary. Being a reference it will automatically removed from the SelectList.

```
routingActions.Remove("Disapprove");
```